# Converting UnitTest to Instrumentation Test in android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-instrumentation

So I started with a UnitTest called MyCoolObjectTest. Needing to do some instrumentation testing, I moved the class right within the `Android` project view from the `test` directory to the `androidTest` directory by dragging. My UnitTest used to work fine; except for the instrumentation portions. But now it does not work at all. I keep getting

```
Class not found: "com.mypkg.MyCoolObjectTest"Empty test suite.
```

I have been looking all over stackOverflow and at the official docs for a solution. No luck so far. Has anyone experienced something similar?

(if I drag it back to the test folder it works; if I re-drag to the androidTest folder it stops working again)

I remember the was a way to set the folder under test. But I no longer remember.

For some insight, I want to use some android library in my test such as

```
public String stripFormatting(String input){
    return Html.fromHtml(input).toString();
}
```

That's why I need instrumentation.

Here is my unit test class with one test for an example:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyCoolObjectTest {
    @Test
    public void testJustToKnow() {
        String actual = "<b>0</b>";
        String expected = "0";
        assertThat(stripFormatting(actual), equalTo(expected));
    }
    public String stripFormatting(String input) {
        return Html.fromHtml(input).toString();
    }
}
```

**update**

Here is a different trace that I got. If I click on the method instead of the class, I get the following trace:

Just now I clicked on the method instead of the whole class, and got the following trace:

> 11/04 13:51:16: Launching testJustToKnow() $ adb push
>   /Users/me/StudioProjects/Myapp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.myapp $ adb shell pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.myapp"     pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.myapp Success
>
> $ adb push
>   /Users/me/StudioProjects/Myapp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.Myapp.test $ adb shell pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.myapp.test"    pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.mypkg.myapp.test Success
>
> Running tests
>
> $ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class
>   com.mypkg.myapp.utils.MyCoolObjectTest#testJustToKnow
>   com.mypkg.myapp.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner Client not
>   ready yet..Test running started
>
> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in
>   com.mypkg.myapp.utils.MyCoolObjectTest at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1959)
>
> Tests ran to completion.

Comment: Can you post the test class ?

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. Here is how I solved it:

- In Android Studio go to Run > Edit Configurations...
- Under the heading **Android JUnit**, select your test and delete it (minus button)
- Add a new test configuration (plus button) and select **Android Instrumented Tests**
- Set the following options:
- Module: app
- Test: Class
- Class: select or enter your class with the instrumentation tests here
- Click OK

Everything should work now.

Comment: In my case there was "step 0" where I had to close and reopen the project. In step 2, the configuration was under "unknown".

Comment: @murf  This one worked. Its weird why Studio is not doing all these automatically... Unfortunately awful with these kinda issues... Thanks murf for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be useful:

- **src/test**: only for unit test (nothing that involve android framework).
- **src/androidTest**: for android instrumentation tests.

Please see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html) a better explanation for this.

[Example of instrumentation test](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) (Please check your annotations, for example `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` or `@SmallTest` or `@Test`)

I hope this will be useful for you.

**(update)**

Maybe you forgot this on your gradle (in the main module):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

If you has using Espresso, you must add a dependency (Please check the link above this "...Example of instrumentation test...")

Comment: `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` is not necessary